# Small Form Factor Thermal Camera

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, arduino

I am Currently Looking for a Thermal Camera which either has an lcd screen which can be be extended away from the camera or simply a high quality thermal camera which can be programed into an lcd. Prefferable at reasonable price that is. Another option that I'm open to also i buying a premade thermal camera but i dont really know which ones can detect small scale temperature differences (I.E Pests on walls or the Ticks on the body of a dog.

Comment: You added the Raspberry Pi tag but don't mention it in the question - is it a necessity to use it with the Pi?

Comment: Yes, either an arduino or a raspberry pi is ok.

Comment: do you accept other forms as well? Stand-alone? Smartphone/tablet attachment? Others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AMG8833](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-amg8833-8x8-thermal-camera-sensor/raspberry-pi-thermal-camera) is a popular thermal camera which has an accuracy of 2.5 °C (4.5 °F). The benefit is that it's commonly used, and has a pretty decent support. The drawback is its tiny resolution, 8×8 pixels only. It costs around $40.

[MLX90640](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14843) is another, although less popular, choice, with its increased resolution of 32×24 pixels and an accuracy of 1.5 °C. You can get it for $70. Using one is more difficult than AMG8833, especially regarding to the hardware requirements:

> Please be aware that the MLX90640 requires complex calculations by the host platform so a regular Arduino Uno (or equivalent) doesn't have enough RAM or flash to complete the complex computations required to turn the raw pixel data into temperature data. You will need a microcontroller with 20,000 bytes or more of RAM. To achieve this, we recommend a Teensy 3.1 or above.

For $240, you can get [Lepton 2.5 thermal camera module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14654) which comes with an impressive resolution of 80×60 pixels, but a disappointing accuracy of only 5 °C.

[Flir website](https://www.flir.com/browse/camera-cores--components/thermal-camera-cores/) lists more models, including [Lepton 3.5 camera core](https://www.flir.com/products/lepton/) with its 50 mK thermal sensitivity (the same as 2.5 version) and a resolution of 160×120 pixels. The camera core seems to be sold for about $270, but I can't find it in a form of a module to be used with Raspberry Pi.

Or you get more specialized models such as [Neutrino SX12](https://www.flir.com/products/neutrino-performance-series/?model=425-0039-00) with a sensitivity of 25 mK and a resolution of 1280×1024 pixels. You'll need something other than a Raspberry Pi to power that thing. I can't find its price, but I won't be surprised to find that you have to pay more than a thousand dollars for a device like that.

Comment: @arsenio  can you help at [thsi question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/12657/thermal-imaging-camera) ? Thanks a 1,000,000